# Can we only see the past of the universe?

Tags: universe

So I was reading some interesting stuff about universe and Big Bang and wanted to make sure one thing. As far as I understand everything we can see about universe is the past, right?

I mean all the galaxies and known stars are many light years away so we have no way to knowing if they still exist, so pretty much we don't know anything about present state of the universe, galaxies and stars. Am I right?

That said, all of the facts are said in present tense like "There are billions of galaxies" or "there are black holes", but in fact, they WERE, because we don't know if they exist now.